# Ionic Framework + NodeJS authentication

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, jwt, passport.js

Last few days I've been struggling with authentication in my application made with Ionic Framework. I am using NodeJS as a backend and passport JWT strategy for athentication. I got it up and running now, but this is my first authentication and I don't know what is the best practice, I've seen a lot of different approaches.

Currently I am saving token to local storage and in my main controller I am checking if user has a token and so on, here is my code:

**mainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('authApp').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, Auth) {
    $scope.currentUser = {};

    if(Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        Auth.getUser().then(function(response) {
            $scope.currentUser = response.data.user;
            console.log(response);
        })
        console.log('User logged in');
    } else {
        $scope.currentUser = false;
        console.log('User not logged in');
    }
});
```

**auth.js**

```
angular.module('authApp').factory('Auth', function($http, API, AuthToken) {
    var service = {};

    service.register = function(user) {
        $http.post(API + '/api/register', user).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function() {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    service.login = function(user) {
        var promise = $http.post(API + '/api/login', user).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            AuthToken.setToken(response.data.token);
        }, function() {
            console.log(response);
        });

        return promise;
    }

    service.logout = function() {
        AuthToken.setToken();
    }

    service.isLoggedIn = function() {
        if(AuthToken.getToken()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    service.getUser = function() {
        if(AuthToken.getToken()) {
            return $http.get(API + '/api/currentuser');
        } else {
            console.log('User has no token');
        }
    }

    return service;
});

angular.module('authApp').factory('AuthToken', function($window) {
    var service = {};

    service.setToken = function(token) {
        if(token) {
            $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);   
        } else {
            $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
        }
    }

    service.getToken = function() {
        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    return service;
});

angular.module('authApp').factory('AuthInterceptors', function(AuthToken) {
    var service = {};

    service.request = function(config) {
        var token = AuthToken.getToken();

        if(token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = token;
        }

        return config;
    }

    return service;
});
```

This works. Eg. in my /profile page, I can show user profile by doing {{ currentUser.name }} etc, but is this best practice, or should I keep current user information somewhere else?